# The affine line with two points removed

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

To which affine variety $V$ is $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0, 1\}$ isomorphic to? What would be the isomorphism in this case? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to show that $\mathbb{A}^1 - \{0\}$ (or any point, really) is an affine variety?

Comment: @Hoot Yes, I do.

Comment: I would try to juice that up somehow — the procedure is more general than you think it is! What you did before is build a bijection between $\mathbb{A}^1 - Z(f)$ and $Z(fy - 1) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$ where $f(x) = x$. The particular $f$ wasn't so important.

Comment: What do you mean, "what is it isomorphic to"? It's isomorphic to itself, via the identity map, for example, but that's not useful, even though it's a perfectly good answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0, 1\} \cong Spec \ k[x,x^{-1},(x-1)^{-1}]$